# What happens when my Python range object stop value is never hit?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, range

I'm learning python and I have a little snippet that is shown below:

```
for i in range(-10, 11, -6):
    print(i)
```

This did not throw up an error nor give an output. Surprisingly I expected an error, since that stop value of `11` would never be hit. Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range represents an immutable sequence of numbers.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) is a documentation of `range` type.

In your case:

1. start = -10
2. stop = 11
3. step = -6

> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.
>
> A range object will be empty if r[0] does not meet the value constraint.

so let's try to generate range first element for your case

```
r[0] = -10 + -6 * 0
r[0] = -10
```

but -10 is less than stop so algorithm stops here producing an empty range

```
>>> range(-10, 11, -6)
[]
```

so in your code range will be equivalent to this:

```
for i in []:  # empty array, 0 iterations of loop, nothing printed to console
    print(i)
```

and this code is perfectly valid python, "iterate over an empty range and finish" - that is why (1) nothing printed as range is empty, and (2) you got no error as code is valid

Comment: you just helped my learning. Thanks. I was working on a Jupyter environment and I also ran ```range(-10, 11, -6)``` the cell executed but no output whatsoever, that caused me to start asking questions.